# Generalized Bekenstein-Hawking temperature for Kerr-Newmann-dS black holes

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation, cosmological-constant, black-hole-thermodynamics, kerr-newman-metric

What is the formula for the Bekenstein-Hawking temperature in a Kerr-Newmann-de Sitter spacetime, i.e., the temperature for a black hole with Mass (M), angular momentum (J), electric charge (Q) and cosmological constant ($\Lambda$)?

Answer (score 1):

Just a small correction, the solution is called Kerr-Newman-dS (without Schwarzschild, because it is just non-rotating Kerr). And a quick search gives a couple of papers:

- [paper 1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0209203v3.pdf)
- [paper 2](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.3680v1.pdf)

Hope this helps and answers your question.